# Anime/Cartoon movie about a girl losing letters in her name and an orphan boy who outlives and buries his village

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, space

The girl is a soldier for this big space organization and she's told a bunch of lies about the universe. The organization is run by her father. (I think he's her adoptive father.)

She is sent on a mission to a planet and she is wearing a space suit and is told "don't breathe the air, it's dangerous." She runs out of air supply and takes her helmet off and passes out. The organization finds her and fixes her but when she wakes up all of the (I think) "K"s in her name are gone.

The boy lives in the village and he has a sister/cousin/friend he plays with. They always sit on a pier. The sister/friend dies and then the village gets on a spaceship?

The villagers start to die and the boy and a young man from the village bury them all together. They periodically visit the graves. (It may be a boat that they are on.) The young guy becomes a father figure to the boy then he dies and the boy buries him with everyone else. He's alone and plays(?) at the graveyard.

It came out in 2010 or earlier, but after the early 1980's.

I might be confusing 2 movies but any help would be good.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubo_and_the_Two_Strings ?